# How to fix facebook expoauthsession sign in Error"Something went wrong trying to finish signing in. Please close this screen to go back to the app"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

[image]

when I try logging in using AuthSession it doesn't redirect me back to app.

I'm using

```
expo-auth-session/providers/facebook
```

to login facebook

Answer (score 0):

```
promptAsync({ useProxy: true })
```